# How to duplicate Git repo but with different name and history?

Tags: git, github, repository, workflow

I've created a component framework repository on GitHub that I want to use as a base repo for future projects.

I know that I can clone the repo locally, but wasn't sure if there's another way of doing it so I can easily rename the new (cloned) project and it have it's own separate git history and a new remote link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can fork the repo.
like that you keep the history, but the next commit will evolve separately from the first repo.
In addition, you keep the link with the original repo if you want some days to integer your change to the first repo.
More information about forking repository here:
https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/fork-a-repo#about-forks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another remote if `git remote add` to the same local repository. This is very useful, for example, when you have a fork of a repository and you want to keep track of both the fork and the upstream.

One example using this workflow: suppose that there's an open-source library that you want to add a new feature for your use case. If it's on GitHub, you can fork the original repository. Then you `git clone` your fork and then add the original lib as a second remote (e.g. `git remote add upstream <url>`). You can check the remotes using `git remote -v`.

As an example, every time you run `git fetch upstream master`, git will download the newer commits of the original repository, and it will be labeled as `upstream/master`. If you want to merge them on you master, then go to your master and run `git merge upstream/master`. This way, you can develop on your fork and regularly update with the newer versions of the original library.

This way, in the same local repository you can keep track of both histories, changing between the two codebases only using `git checkout`.